# How to add an additional field to the dataset in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am working on preparing a vega chart and my dataset is as follows:

```
data: {
"values": [
  {"key": "title1", "value": "100"},
  {"key": "title2", "value": "500"},
  {"key": "title3", "value": "400"},
  {"key": "title4", "value": "200"},
  {"key": "title5", "value": "600"},
  {"key": "title6", "value": "50"},
  {"key": "title7", "value": "10"}
]}
```

I want to add another field 'result' to this array whose value is based on the existing value field.

For example:

result['title1'] = value['title1'] / value['title2']

result['title2'] = value['title2'] / value['title3']

Output:

```
data: {
"values": [
  {"key": "title1", "value": "100", "result": 0.2},
  {"key": "title2", "value": "500", "result": 1.25},
  ...
]}
```

I tried using transform in vega-lite but was not able to achieve it.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: What about the last value? What is the divided by?

Comment: Hi @David, this is just an example. I want to know how to add a new field whose value is calculated based on other existing fields.

Comment: In that case, you need to use the window transform. That allows you to create a moving window across the dataset.

Comment: Hi @David, I was able to achieve this by using the window transform. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear it worked - well done. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window transform as per comments.